# Save state in file on cleanup using __del__?

Tags: python, del, resource-cleanup

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, filename, sources):
        # gather info from file
        # info is updated during lifetime of the object

    def close(self):
        # save info back to file
```

Now, this is in a server program, so it might be shutdown without prior notice by a signal. Is it safe to define this to make sure the class saves it's info, if possible?

```
def __del__(self):
    self.close()
```

If not, what would you suggest as a solution instead?

Comment: Don't use '__del__' for this kind of thing.  It's not guaranteed to be called, ever, in the lifetime of your process run, not even at exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting until later is just not the strategy to making something reliable.  In fact, you have to go the complete opposite direction.  As soon as you know something that should be persistent, you need to take action to persist it.  In fact, if you want to make it reliable, you need to first write to disk the steps needed to *recover from the failure* that might happen while you are trying to commit the change.  pseudopython:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, filename, sources):
        self.recover()
        # gather info from file
        # info is updated during lifetime of the object

    def update_info(self, info):
        # append 'info' to recovery_log
        # recovery_log.flush()
        # write 'info' to file
        # file.flush()
        # append 'info-SUCCESS' to recover_log
        # recovery_log.flush()

    def recover(self):
        # open recovery_log
        # skip to last 'info-SUCCESS'
        # read 'info' from recover_log
        # write 'info' to file
        # file.flush()
        # append 'info-SUCCESS' to recover_log
        # recovery_log.flush()
```

The important bit is that `recover()` happens every time, and that every step is followed by a `flush()` to make sure data makes it out to disk before the next step occurs.  another important thing is that only appends ever occur on the recover log itself.  nothing is overwritten in such a way that the data in the log can become corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are **NEVER** safe.

If the opearting system wants to kill you without prior notice, it will. You can do nothing about it. Your program can stop running after any instruction, at any time, and have no opportunity to execute any additional code.

There is just no way of protecting your server from a killing signal.

You can, if you want, trap lesser signals and manually delete your objects, forcing the calls to `close()`.

Comment: I know I'm never safe. I want to know how I can automatically clean up, if possible.

Comment: You can use exit hooks. See Keith's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For orderly cleanup you can use the [sys.atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) hooks. Register a function there that calls your close method. The destructor of on object may not be called at exit.

Comment: I'd recommend against atexit.  You're a lot better off designing to have a predictable exit/cleanup path.

Comment: True, it would be better in this context to not keep unsaved information around for too long, and use context managers. But atexit can be helpful to adapt an already not-so-good design to something safer.

Answer (score 1):

The `__del__` method is [not guaranteed](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) to ever be called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Even if `__del__` is called, it can be called too late.  In particular, it can occur after modules it wants to call have been unloaded.  As pointed out by Keith, [sys.atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) is much safer.

Comment: I don't think that can ever happen.  When a `__del__` method is called, it still has a reference to any modules imported into its scope and to any objects referenced from `self`, so they can't be cleaned up yet.  Python will omit the call to `__del__` rather than run it out of order, if necessary.

Comment: docs say: *"It is not guaranteed that \__del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits"*